# how to implement background tasks in react native using headless js so a fetch api runs indefinetely in all 3 states

Tags: reactjs, expo, react-native, react-native-ios

how to run fetch api indefinitely in react native apps?

I am new to react native development but I found that I can keep a task running in android infinitely through headless Js. Is it the only way or there is another method? I just want to fetch api.

If headless JS does this task can someone explain how to do so since i am unable to understand their docs. It should satisfy{foreground/background/killed}.when there is data in api i need it to give a notification using react native notification